# Weather API for web app

Tags: xml, web-services, api, weather

In the weather.com site it has forecast for 10 days. 
For example, in this url: http://www.weather.com/weather/narrative/GRXX0004

I cannot seem to find a feed for that kind of data. Could I pull a feed for each one of those days?
Is there something I am missing? How could I easily parse data for 10 days?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched for a little bit for tutorials on using Weather.com's data feeds- it looks like this [site](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=18#howto) provides some source code that allows you to use the weather gateway class to enter a given location as a parameter which then "can look up the weather for this location. You can choose to get current conditions, or detailed forecast reports for days to come".

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to figure it out. Nice resource! :)

Comment: Glad to be of some help- G'luck

Comment: @john - Make sure to mark this as the correct answer if it was able to help you out with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [National Weather Service](http://www.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/) XML data feeds.